# how to check which dns client is used on an external server?

Tags: dns, bind

The issue is that i cannot determine what domain name system external servers use.

I want to be able to spot which kind of domain name system client is a server using without having actually access to it.

I have tried several commands on n map with domain name system searching script, but the result is not clear.

For ports open i can use n map.

Is there a solution for domain name system spotting too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing within the DNS protocol which will do what you are asking for. Which port does not matter as port 53 is the standard DNS port and all DNS server regardless of what software they are running will respond on port 53 and will return data in the same way. Without access to the remote server you would not be able to identify what DNS server software they are running.